# Firebase Android Facebook Authentication, Authentication Failed

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use facebook firebase authentication in my app but in the app when I try to login with facebook.Task failed part works. I don't understand why. Maybe it's because I am using a custom button. Please help me. Here is the code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        Log.d("Success", "Login");

                        handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "İptal Edildi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);

        facebook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(Login.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
            }
        });
    }
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(currentUser != null){
            startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, Loggedin.class));
    }

}
    private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
        AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, Loggedin.class));

                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Have you added `compile project(':facebook-android-sdk-4.20.0')` in your `build.gradle` file?

Answer (score 0):

Put these lines before setContentView(R.layout.login);

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
```